# iOS WKWebView 's didCommitNavigation never called?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

In my test code , I open the http://www.qq.com/ with a WKWebView .
And I found that ,there will be 3 delegate methods to be called:

```
webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:
webView:(WKWebView *)webView didStartProvisionalNavigation:
webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:
```

And these two method will never be called

```
webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:
webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:
```

And I want to know what make the method to be called or not ?

Comment: why close ？this question is very clear and valuable for others、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the reason here: it's because my webview is using the WebViewJavaScriptBridge , and this bridge cause the two method will not be called . so if u need these two method to working ,do it as follows
https://blog.csdn.net/zyx980193917/article/details/107064789